# Check if dataframe column is Categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to get a simple dtype check working with Pandas' improved Categoricals in v0.15+. Basically I just want something like `is_categorical(column) -> True/False`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.linspace(0, 50, 6),
    'y': np.linspace(0, 20, 6),
    'cat_column': random.sample('abcdef', 6)
})
df['cat_column'] = pd.Categorical(df2['cat_column'])
```

We can see that the `dtype` for the categorical column is 'category':

```
df.cat_column.dtype
Out[20]: category
```

And normally we can do a dtype check by just comparing to the name
of the dtype:

```
df.x.dtype == 'float64'
Out[21]: True
```

But this doesn't seem to work when trying to check if the `x` column
is categorical:

```
df.x.dtype == 'category'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-94d2608815c4> in <module>()
----> 1 df.x.dtype == 'category'

TypeError: data type "category" not understood
```

Is there any way to do these types of checks in pandas v0.15+?

Comment: so aside from the below solns, the canoncial way to select columns >= 0.15.0 is ``df.select_dtypes(include=['category'])``

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact that `category` is a data type added by pandas, compared to other data types that comes from numpy.

Comment: @AntoineGallix Yes, the problem is that `numpy.dtype` is checking if the datatype name "category" is a recognized category name (like "float64"). Since its not recognized in `numpy` (no categorical datatype in numpy), numpy assumes you made a typo, rather than telling you its definitely not the datatype you're looking for. Pandas on the other hand has chosen the other approach, typos result in plain-old `False`.

Comment: i notice that df.x.dtype == 'category' works in pandas 1.3.4 but not in pandas 1.0.3

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use the `name` property to do the comparison instead, it should always work because it's just a string:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr.dtype.name
'int64'

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> cat = pd.Categorical(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> cat.dtype.name
'category'
```

So, to sum up, you can end up with a simple, straightforward function:

```
def is_categorical(array_like):
    return array_like.dtype.name == 'category'
```

Answer (score 33):

First, the string representation of the dtype is `'category'` and not `'categorical'`, so this works:

```
In [41]: df.cat_column.dtype == 'category'
Out[41]: True
```

But indeed, as you noticed, this comparison gives a `TypeError` for other dtypes, so you would have to wrap it with a `try .. except ..` block.

---

Other ways to check using pandas internals:

```
In [42]: isinstance(df.cat_column.dtype, pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype)
Out[42]: True

In [43]: pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(df.cat_column)
Out[43]: True
```

For non-categorical columns, those statements will return `False` instead of raising an error. For example:

```
In [44]: pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(df.x)
Out[44]: False
```

For much older version of `pandas`, replace `pd.api.types` in the above snippet with `pd.core.common`.

Comment: Which columns would it give an error for?

Comment: With recent versions of numpy this no longer errors, but previously something like `np.dtype("int64" == "category"` raised an error instead of returning False.

Comment: In `pandas v2.1.0` this results in a FutureWarning. Instead use `isinstance(df.x, pd.CategoricalDtype)` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60975887/7758804)

Answer (score 6):

Just putting this here because [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) is what I was *actually* looking for:

```
df['column'].name in df.select_dtypes(include='category').columns
```

Thanks to @Jeff.

Answer (score 5):

In my pandas version (v1.0.3), a shorter version of joris' answer is available.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'noncat': [1, 2, 3], 'categ': pd.Categorical(['A', 'B', 'C'])})

print(isinstance(df.noncat.dtype, pd.CategoricalDtype))  # False
print(isinstance(df.categ.dtype, pd.CategoricalDtype))   # True

print(pd.CategoricalDtype.is_dtype(df.noncat)) # False
print(pd.CategoricalDtype.is_dtype(df.categ))  # True
```

Comment: I get unexpected results with my data 

``
isinstance(Tmanual['X'], pd.CategoricalDtype)
Out[216]: False

Tmanual['REVENUES_FAST'].dtype.name == 'category'
Out[217]: True

Tmanual['X'].dtype
Out[218]: CategoricalDtype(categories=['ANY', 'ANYIMPORTANT', 'BX', 'OPTIONAL'], ordered=False)
``

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this thread looking for the exact same functionality, and also found out another option, right from the pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-is-not-a-numpy-array).

It looks like the canonical way to check if a pandas dataframe column is a categorical Series should be the following:

```py
hasattr(column_to_check, 'cat')
```

So, as per the example given in the initial question, this would be:

```py
hasattr(df.x, 'cat') #True
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at @Jeff Tratner answer, since the condition `df.cat_column.dtype == 'category'` not needs to be `True` to be considered a column as cataegorical,
I propose this considering categorical the dtypes within 'categorical_dtypes' list:

```
def is_cat(column):
    categorical_dtypes = ['object', 'category', 'bool']
    if column.dtype.name in categorical_dtypes:
        return True
    else:
        return False   

´´´
```