# Check which columns in DataFrame are Categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas... I want to a simple and generic way to find which columns are `categorical` in my `DataFrame`, when I don't manually specify each column type, unlike in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924904/check-if-dataframe-column-is-categorical). The `df` is created with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None)
```

e.g.

```
           0         1         2         3        4
0   1.539240  0.423437 -0.687014   Chicago   Safari
1   0.815336  0.913623  1.800160    Boston   Safari
2   0.821214 -0.824839  0.483724  New York   Safari
```

.

**UPDATE (2018/02/04) The question assumes numerical columns are NOT categorical, @Zero's [accepted answer solves this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803290/1910555).**

**BE CAREFUL:
As @Sagarkar's comment points out that's not always true.** The difficulty is that Data Types and Categorical/Ordinal/Nominal types are orthogonal concepts, thus mapping between them isn't straightforward.

**@Jeff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29821799/1910555) below specifies the precise manner to achieve the manual mapping.**

Comment: For a good source on Pandas and Categorical Data, read p363/Chp12 [‘Advanced Pandas’ in ‘Python for Data Analysis’ (O’Reilly,2017) by Wes McKinney.](https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could use `df._get_numeric_data()` to get numeric columns and then find out categorical columns

```
In [66]: cols = df.columns

In [67]: num_cols = df._get_numeric_data().columns

In [68]: num_cols
Out[68]: Index([u'0', u'1', u'2'], dtype='object')

In [69]: list(set(cols) - set(num_cols))
Out[69]: ['3', '4']
```

Comment: So numeric columns can't be categorical? I don't think that is a good way to do this.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The encoding of a categorical variable can be e.g. with integers or one-hot encoding. With this method that would be lost.

Comment: @Astrid Well, the whole idea is that you must check what columns are categorical _before_ doing the encoding. If you already have an encoding then this means you _already know_ that such columns were categorical.

Comment: OP evidently does not know that the columns are categorical a priori. So this method remains unsatisfactory. You can still encode without knowing what type your column are, this is common in fact, but you'll loose distance relationships if yout column is e.g. Ordinal.

Comment: @SagarKar and @Astrid, with this assumption in place the only way is to have a look into the data dictionary or, but it's an heuristic only, check if e.g. `.nunique()` <= some arbitrary low value.

Answer (score 54):

The way I found was updating to Pandas v0.16.0, then excluding number dtypes with:

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude=["number","bool_","object_"])
```

Which works, providing no types are changed and no more are added to NumPy. The suggestion in [the question's comments by @Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924904/check-if-dataframe-column-is-categorical) suggests `include=["category"]`, but that didn't seem to work.

**NumPy Types:** [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html)

[image: Numpy Types]

Comment: A great visual. Where would the `category` example of Jeff's fit in it?

Comment: Both `include='category'` and `include=['category']` work for me, when the `dtype` is actually set to `'category'` (not `'object'`)

Answer (score 30):

For posterity. The canonical method to select dtypes is `.select_dtypes`. You can specify an actual numpy dtype or convertible, or 'category' which not a numpy dtype.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'A' : Series(range(3)).astype('category'), 'B' : range(3), 'C' : list('abc'), 'D' : np.random.randn(3) })

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   A  B  C         D
0  0  0  a  0.141296
1  1  1  b  0.939059
2  2  2  c -2.305019

In [3]: df.select_dtypes(include=['category'])
Out[3]: 
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2

In [4]: df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
Out[4]: 
   C
0  a
1  b
2  c

In [5]: df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).dtypes
Out[5]: 
C    object
dtype: object

In [6]: df.select_dtypes(include=['category','int']).dtypes
Out[6]: 
A    category
B       int64
dtype: object

In [7]: df.select_dtypes(include=['category','int','float']).dtypes
Out[7]: 
A    category
B       int64
D     float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Suggest a possible merge of this and the community-edited `.select_dtypes()` answer that preceeded it (?). Not that I want you to lose the upvotes.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: @ samisnotinsane, genuinely, should the question be changed? The underlying problem is that we want a low effort answer to a harder question and we want Pandas to solve it for us, but it doesn't/ it can't So the workaround is @Jeff's answer (i.e. No Free Lunch). The marked cheap answer (is wrong and) makes an assumption about how data types and categorical types are often (but not always) linked. So, how does SO deal with this? I do not know.

Comment: @Jeff, would you find it suitable to add a "No you can't" (or similar) and an example? The example would match the question, i.e. load df via `df = read_csv()`, set a `column` after loading df with an `astype('category')`, and then `df.select_dtypes(include=['category'])` then show the category column(s) data. If so, I think this would be the best answer, and your 6 y.o. answer nearly has this already.

Answer (score 21):

You can get the list of categorical columns using this code :

```
dfName.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.tolist()
```

And intuitively for numerical columns :

```
dfName.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns.tolist()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

select categorical column names

`cat_features=[i for i in df.columns if df.dtypes[i]=='object']`

Answer (score 6):

# Get categorical and numerical variables

```
numCols = X.select_dtypes("number").columns
catCols = X.select_dtypes("object").columns
numCols= list(set(numCols))
catCols= list(set(catCols))
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to query the data if you are just interested in which columns are of what type.

The fastest method (when `%%timeit`-ing it) is:

```py
df.dtypes[df.dtypes == 'category'].index
```

*(this will give you a pandas' `Index`. You can `.tolist()` to get a list out of it, if you need that.)*

This works because `df.dtypes` is a `pd.Series` of strings (its own dtype is `'object'`), so you can actually just select for the type that you need with normal pandas querying.

You don't have your categorical types as `'category'` but as simple strings (`'object'`)? Then just:

```py
df.dtypes[df.dtypes == 'object'].index
```

Do you have a mix of `'object'` and `'category'`? Then use `isin` like you would do normally to query for multiple matches:

```py
df.dtypes[df.dtypes.isin(['object','category'])].index
```

Answer (score 4):

```
numeric_var = [key for key in dict(df.dtypes)
                   if dict(pd.dtypes)[key]
                       in ['float64','float32','int32','int64']] # Numeric Variable

cat_var = [key for key in dict(df.dtypes)
             if dict(df.dtypes)[key] in ['object'] ] # Categorical Varible
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with the community standards. Always try to make your answers as readable as possible!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for providing code which might help solve the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Comment: The line `if dict(pd.dtypes)[key]` should read, I believe, `if dict(df.dtypes)[key]`.

Answer (score 4):

Often columns get pandas dtype of string (or "object")  or category. Better to include both incase the columns you look for don't get listed under category dtype.

`dataframe.select_dtypes(include=['object','category']).columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

Use .dtypes

```
In [10]: df.dtypes
Out[10]: 
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
3     object
4     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: df.dtypes is iterable, so that works. But what would the generic if condition would be?... != "float64" and != "int64" ... etc..

Answer (score 2):

Use **pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes**. There are **categorical** dtypes that can be found by 'categorical' flag. For **Strings** you might use the numpy *object* dtype

More Info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Exemple:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Integer': [1, 2] * 3,'Bool': [True, False] * 3,'Float': [1.0, 2.0] * 3,'String': ['Dog', 'Cat'] * 3})
df

Out[1]:    
    Integer Bool    Float   String
0   1       True    1.0     Dog
1   2       False   2.0     Cat
2   1       True    1.0     Dog
3   2       False   2.0     Cat
4   1       True    1.0     Dog
5   2       False   2.0     Cat

df.select_dtypes(include=['category', object]).columns

Out[2]:
Index(['String'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar obstacle where categorizing variables was a challenge. However I came up with some approaches based on the nature of the data. This would give a general and flexible answer to your issue as well as to future data.

*Normally while categorization of data is done on the basis of its datatype which sometimes may result in wrong analysis. (Usually done by df.select_dtypes(include = ['object', 'category'])*

**Approach**:

- The approach is of viewing the data not on a column level but on a row level. This approach would give the number of distinct values which would automatically distinguish categorical variables from numerical types.
- That is if count of unique values in a row exceed more than certain number of values
  (This is for you to decide how many categorical variables you presume in your column)

for eg: `if ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish', 'Reptile']` makes up for five unique categorical values for a particular column and if number of distinct values don't exceed more than those five unique categorical values in that column then that column falls under categorical variables.

`elif ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish', 'Reptile']` makes up for five unique categorical values for a particular column and if number of distinct values exceed more than those five unique categorical values in that column then they fall under numerical variables.

```
if [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique()) <=5]:
     cat_var = [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique()) <=5]  
elif [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique()) > 5]:
     num_var = [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique()) > 5]

# where 5 : presumed number of categorical variables and may be flexible for user to decide.
```

I have used `if` and `elif` for better illustration. There is no need for that you can directly go for lines inside the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your lateral thoughts - I hope they spark ideas for others . However,... the problem is that your approach is just arbitrarily "moving the goal posts"; the common underlying assumption is "datatype determines categorical", your approach is "quantity of unique data values determines categorical" - but simply neither are true. I mean, it can work, but "neither define categorical" as a concept.

Answer (score 1):

```
`categorical_values  = (df.dtypes == 'object')
categorical_variables = categorical_variables =[categorical_values.index[ind] 
for ind, val in enumerate(categorical_values) if val == True]
```

In the first line of code, we obtain a series which gives information regarding all the columns. The series gives information on which column is an object type and which column is not of the object type by representing it with a Boolean value.

In the second line, we use a list comprehension using enumeration(iterating through index and value), so that we could easily find the column which is of categorical type and append it to the categorical_variables list

Answer (score 1):

First we can segregate the data frame with the default types available when we read the datasets. This will list out all the different types and the corresponding data.

```
for types in data.dtypes.unique():
    print(types)
    print(data.select_dtypes(types).columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will get all categorical variables:

```
cat_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in df.describe().columns]
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works? Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

This will give an array of all the categorical variables in a dataframe.

```
dataset.select_dtypes(include=['O']).columns.values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : ["France", "Spain", "Germany", "Spain", "Germany", "France"], 
                   "Age" : [34, 27, 30, 32, 42, 30], 
                   "Purchased" : ["No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"]})
df

Out[1]:
  Country Age Purchased
0  France  34        No
1   Spain  27       Yes
2 Germany  30        No
3   Spain  32        No
4 Germany  42       Yes
5  France  30       Yes

# Checking data type
df.dtypes

Out[2]: 
Country      object
Age           int64
Purchased    object
dtype: object

# Saving CATEGORICAL Variables
cat_col = [c for i, c in enumerate(df.columns) if df.dtypes[i] in [np.object]]
cat_col
Out[3]: ['Country', 'Purchased']
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. But you need to check the columns with slightly less than 10 characters, or you need to check columns with unique values that are slightly more than 10 characters manually.

```
def find_cate(df):
cols=df.columns
i=0
for col in cols:
    if len(df[col].unique())<=10:
        print(col,len(df[col].unique()))
        i=i+1
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude=["number"]).columns
```

This will help you to directly display all the non numerical rows

Answer (score 0):

This always worked pretty well for me :

```
categorical_columns = list(set(df.columns) - set(df.describe().columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn gives you a one liner (or a 2 liner if you want to use it on many DataFrames).  Lets say your DataFrame object is df then:

```
## good example in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_stack_predictors.html
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
        
cat_cols = make_column_selector(dtype_include=object) (df)
print (cat_cols)
## OR to use with many DataFrames, create one _selector object first
num_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number) 
num_cols = num_selector (df)
print (num_cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of categorical columns using this code :

`categorical_columns = (df.dtypes == 'object')`

get categorical columns names: 
`object_cols = list(categorical_columns[categorical_columns].index)`