# Find type of data in each column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have read this link: [Check which columns in DataFrame are Categorical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803093/check-which-columns-in-dataframe-are-categorical?lq=1)

I have a dataframe where salaries are mentioned with a $ prepended to it. It is also being shown as categorical data.

Moreover suppose my nominal data is not in form of strings such as 'F','M' etc.
Then how do we classify which columns are numeric, categorical (with strings) and nominal?

Say my data looks like this:

```
ID    Gender   Salary   HasPet  
1      M       $250       0
2      F       $5000      0
3      M       $4500      1
```

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thank you for adding sample. What is desired output?

Comment: @jezrael  
I want to know which columns are numeric,categorical(with strings) and nominal data.In the link given, they have found the numeric data. But what in case of salary, due to the $ sign, it is being shown as non numeric and hence tagged as categorical data

Comment: Suppose your DataFrame is df, how about ```df.dtypes``` or ```df.info()```?

Comment: for salary it will give me object I guess. And for nominal data having 0-1 it will show me int64

Comment: You want a column containing strings to be classified as numeric? Based on what criteria?

Comment: salary shouldnt be categorical data right?

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing [categorical](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html) data type with [strings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) (pandas shows it as `object`).

Numbers can't contain `$` dollar sign by their nature and because of that pandas consider `Salary` column as string and this is **correct** behavior!

You can easily convert your salary column to integer/float if you want though:

```
In [180]: df
Out[180]:
   Gender Salary
0       F  $3283
1       M  $6958
2       F  $3721
3       F  $7732
4       M  $7198
5       F  $5475
6       F  $7410
7       M  $8673
8       F  $8582
9       M  $4115
10      F  $8658
11      F  $6331
12      M  $6174
13      F  $6261
14      M  $6212

In [181]: df.dtypes
Out[181]:
Gender    object
Salary    object
dtype: object
```

let's remove leading `$` and convert `Salary` to `int`:

```
In [182]: df.Salary = df.Salary.str.lstrip('$').astype(int)

In [183]: df.dtypes
Out[183]:
Gender    object
Salary     int32
dtype: object
```

and your `Gender` column to categorical:

```
In [186]: df.Gender = df.Gender.astype('category')

In [187]: df.dtypes
Out[187]:
Gender    category
Salary       int32
dtype: object
```