# Detect which columns are categorical in a dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I want to build an algorithm that can detect which columns are categorical in a dataframe and which are numerical.

Let's have a look at this dataset (just as an example) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12324, 26342, 62438], "passengerClass": [1, 2, 2], "nationality": ["FR", "ES", "US"]})
```

I can assume that categorical data are object/category types :

```
df.dtypes()
```

As we can see the "nationality" column is detected as an object type which is great.
The problem is that the "ID" column and the "passengerClass" are detected as int64 type but are categorical.

Is there a way to detect that these columns are also categorical?
(I also thought about unique values but if we measure the speed of lots of cars it won't be the same at any time. Same for increasing values because sometimes we can delete rows and the ids won't be in the right order)

Zero proposed that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803290/13919003
But in his answer, he doesn't care about int or float being categorical columns which is the case in the « passengerClass » column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check which columns in DataFrame are Categorical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803093/check-which-columns-in-dataframe-are-categorical)

Comment: `df.dtypes.isin(["object", "category"])`?

Comment: It doesn’t because int64 can be categorical data (look at the passengerClass column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12324, 26342, 62438], "passengerClass": [1, 2, 2], "nationality": ["FR", "ES", "US"]})
df = df.astype('category')
print(df.dtypes)
```

**Output:**

```
ID                category
passengerClass    category
nationality       category
dtype: object
```

**Note:**

> In the above example, all the columns are converted to "category", but you can explicitly specify `dtype` for individual columns.

*----- Alternative Option -----*

> You can create config file to explicitly specify columns name with dtype:

**Config File:**

```
[
  {
    "columnName": "ID",
    "columnDtype": "category"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "passengerClass",
    "columnDtype": "category"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "nationality",
    "columnDtype": "category"
  }
]
```

**Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12324, 26342, 62438], "passengerClass": [1, 2, 2], "nationality": ["FR", "ES", "US"]})

with open('./config.json') as cf:
    configList = json.load(cf)

for col in configList:
    colName = col['columnName']
    colType = col['columnDtype']
    df[colName] = df[colName].astype(colType)

print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: In my project, I have over 80 columns and this algorithm is supposed to do everything automatically ... So your idea is not working :/

Comment: @Bonsaï, added a new code snippet to assign column dtypes dynamically.

Comment: I still need to write the config file ?

Comment: No need to add all columns into config file. This config option will give you more control to assign specific dtype to columns of your choice !

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically ? I have 46 categorical columns in my project (not the example) that doesn’t have the category type. If I use the config file I will have to write something like 100 lines...