# Using sklearn ColumnTransformer on more than one column using a list

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, multiple-columns

I am trying to use sklearn ColumnTransformer on more that one column.  I'm getting this error when trying to fit the created transformer:

```
TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['int', 'str']
```

This is how I create the transformer object:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
columns_to_encode = categorical_features_indices
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), 
X.columns[columns_to_encode].tolist())], remainder='passthrough')
```

This code runs without an error.

This is how I now want to fit / encode, and what causes the error:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

This is the input to the code above:

```
print(X.info(), "\n\n")
print(type(columns_to_encode))
columns_to_encode
print("\n\n", X.columns[columns_to_encode].tolist())
```

The code gives this result:

```
RangeIndex: 1460 entries, 0 to 1459
Data columns (total 74 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   MSSubClass     1460 non-null   int64  
 1   MSZoning       1460 non-null   object 
 2   LotFrontage    1460 non-null   float64
 3   LotArea        1460 non-null   int64  
 4   Street         1460 non-null   object 
 5   LotShape       1460 non-null   object 
 6   LandContour    1460 non-null   object 
 7   Utilities      1460 non-null   object 
 8   LotConfig      1460 non-null   object 
 9   LandSlope      1460 non-null   object 
 10  Neighborhood   1460 non-null   object 
 11  Condition1     1460 non-null   object 
 12  Condition2     1460 non-null   object 
 13  BldgType       1460 non-null   object 
 14  HouseStyle     1460 non-null   object 
 15  OverallQual    1460 non-null   int64  
 16  OverallCond    1460 non-null   int64  
 17  YearBuilt      1460 non-null   int64  
 18  YearRemodAdd   1460 non-null   int64  
 19  RoofStyle      1460 non-null   object 
 20  RoofMatl       1460 non-null   object 
 21  Exterior1st    1460 non-null   object 
 22  Exterior2nd    1460 non-null   object 
 23  MasVnrType     1460 non-null   object 
 24  MasVnrArea     1460 non-null   float64
 25  ExterQual      1460 non-null   object 
 26  ExterCond      1460 non-null   object 
 27  Foundation     1460 non-null   object 
 28  BsmtQual       1460 non-null   object 
 29  BsmtCond       1460 non-null   object 
 30  BsmtExposure   1460 non-null   object 
 31  BsmtFinType1   1460 non-null   object 
 32  BsmtFinSF1     1460 non-null   int64  
 33  BsmtFinType2   1460 non-null   object 
 34  BsmtFinSF2     1460 non-null   int64  
 35  BsmtUnfSF      1460 non-null   int64  
 36  TotalBsmtSF    1460 non-null   int64  
 37  Heating        1460 non-null   object 
 38  HeatingQC      1460 non-null   object 
 39  CentralAir     1460 non-null   object 
 40  Electrical     1460 non-null   object 
 41  1stFlrSF       1460 non-null   int64  
 42  2ndFlrSF       1460 non-null   int64  
 43  LowQualFinSF   1460 non-null   int64  
 44  GrLivArea      1460 non-null   int64  
 45  BsmtFullBath   1460 non-null   int64  
 46  BsmtHalfBath   1460 non-null   int64  
 47  FullBath       1460 non-null   int64  
 48  HalfBath       1460 non-null   int64  
 49  BedroomAbvGr   1460 non-null   int64  
 50  KitchenAbvGr   1460 non-null   int64  
 51  KitchenQual    1460 non-null   object 
 52  TotRmsAbvGrd   1460 non-null   int64  
 53  Functional     1460 non-null   object 
 54  Fireplaces     1460 non-null   int64  
 55  GarageType     1460 non-null   object 
 56  GarageYrBlt    1460 non-null   float64
 57  GarageFinish   1460 non-null   object 
 58  GarageCars     1460 non-null   int64  
 59  GarageArea     1460 non-null   int64  
 60  GarageQual     1460 non-null   object 
 61  GarageCond     1460 non-null   object 
 62  PavedDrive     1460 non-null   object 
 63  WoodDeckSF     1460 non-null   int64  
 64  OpenPorchSF    1460 non-null   int64  
 65  EnclosedPorch  1460 non-null   int64  
 66  3SsnPorch      1460 non-null   int64  
 67  ScreenPorch    1460 non-null   int64  
 68  PoolArea       1460 non-null   int64  
 69  MiscVal        1460 non-null   int64  
 70  MoSold         1460 non-null   int64  
 71  YrSold         1460 non-null   int64  
 72  SaleType       1460 non-null   object 
 73  SaleCondition  1460 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(3), int64(33), object(38)
memory usage: 844.2+ KB
None 



array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
       36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52,
       53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,
       71, 72, 73])


 ['MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'LotArea', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'KitchenQual', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Functional', 'Fireplaces', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond', 'PavedDrive', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition']
```

All help and pointers much appreciated.

Comment: You have used all your columns as categorical, see when you print columns_to_encode it's all the columns. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803093/check-which-columns-in-dataframe-are-categorical

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day :-)