# How I detect categorical variables on my dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, eda

I am analyzing a dataset, and I'm aiming to determine whether the variables are categorical or not. However, I encountered a challenge where variables of type 'int64' or 'float64' might potentially be categorical. I am looking to resolve this using Python.

I tried to classify it by the type of the variables but like i said before 'int64' and 'float64' also can be categorical.

Comment: if you speak about pandas categorical, you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924904/check-if-dataframe-column-is-categorical  if you want to determine if a column have small possible values, you need to determine how much is "small" and you can use unique to find all the possibilities in the column

Comment: an example of the data and expected output ?